# Unable to install packages with pip install ( behind corporate proxy)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Unable to install python packages by "pip install pandas".

I am behid corporate proxy.
Environment variable for HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY is also set but still unable to install packages

pip config edit gives following log

proxy = https://192.168.0.1:8080
timeout = 60

Also tried ( as suggested by Say. W )

> pip -v --log /tmp/pip.log --trusted-host pypi.python.org
>   --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install pandas

but still same error

Please help to suggest how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Gaurav

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Gaurav Patni> pip -v --log /tmp/pip.log install pandas
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\GAURAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-nmlmjzjs
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\GAURAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-qqduq1_c
Created requirements tracker 'C:\\Users\\GAURAV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-qqduq1_c'
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\GAURAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4dysob1h
Collecting pandas
  1 location(s) to search for versions of pandas:
  * https: //pypi.org/simple/pandas/
  Getting page https: //pypi.org/simple/pandas/
  Looking up "https: //pypi.org/simple/pandas/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pandas/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError(
'Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host',
 None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/

Starting new HTTPS connection (6): pypi.org:443
  Could not fetch URL https: //pypi.org/simple/pandas/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
 Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(1
0054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
Cleaning up...

Removed build tracker 'C:\\Users\\GAURAV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-qqduq1_c'
No matching distribution found for pandas
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)

  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)

  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)

  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes

  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 269, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)

  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 196, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)

  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 688, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req

pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for pandas
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
* https: //pypi.org/simple/pip/
Getting page https: //pypi.org/simple/pip/
Looking up "https: //pypi.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
Could not fetch URL https: //pypi.org/simple/pip/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out'))) 
- skipping
PS C:\Users\Gaurav Patni> pip -v --log /tmp/pip.log install pandas^Apip -v --log /tmp/pip.log install pandaspip -v --log
 /tmp/pip.log install pandas
```

Comment: The following error message: "Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out')))" means that either the proxy is OFF or you don't have the right address_ip/port for the proxy. Do you have a "proxy.pac" definition from within your company ? Usually you may download it, and look inside as a text file to identify the right address_ip/port for the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
pip -v --log /tmp/pip.log --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install pandas
```

Comment: Tried 
 pip -v --log /tmp/pip.log --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install pandas
 But still same error  .... Any other suggestion ?